# React display condition

Tags: reactjs, json, api, rest, if-statement

I'm trying to display a message fetched from an API, but sometimes it's Message Packs I get, kind of like this:

[image]
[image]

In first image, we can see "isPack" on False and i have "message" (without "s")
In second image, we have "isPack" on True and i have "messages", is an array with other messages.
I can stock all data and display "current_data.message" but i cant display "current_data.messages" because is an array. And .map() doesnt work (he display me : [object Object]1[object Object]1[object Object]1)

My component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, ChangeEvent } from "react";
import TutorialDataService from "../services/TutorialService";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ITutorialData from "../types/Tutorial";
import { Form, Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";
import IconLoupe from "../assets/IconLoupe.png";

const TutorialsList: React.FC = () => {
  const [tutorials, setTutorials] = useState<Array<ITutorialData>>([]);
  const [currentTutorial, setCurrentTutorial] = useState<ITutorialData | null>(
    null
  );
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState<number>(-1);
  const [searchTitle, setSearchTitle] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveTutorials();
  }, []);

  const onChangeSearchTitle = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const searchTitle = e.target.value;
    setSearchTitle(searchTitle);
  };

  const retrieveTutorials = () => {
    TutorialDataService.getAll()
      .then((response: any) => {
        setTutorials(response.data.data.favourite_conseils);
        console.log(response.data.data.favourite_conseils);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  const refreshList = () => {
    retrieveTutorials();
    setCurrentTutorial(null);
    setCurrentIndex(-1);
  };

  const setActiveTutorial = (tutorial: ITutorialData, index: number) => {
    setCurrentTutorial(tutorial);
    setCurrentIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className="list row">
      <span className="font-link-bold" style={{ fontSize: "26px" }}>
        <span className="font-link-blue-bold">Mes</span> Conseils
      </span>
      <br />
      <br />
      <span
        className="font-link"
        style={{ fontSize: "16px", color: "#657273" }}
      >
        Saisir vos mots-clés ou coller un texte :
      </span>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div className="col-md-8">
        <div className="input-group mb-3">
          <form action="/" method="GET" className="form">
            <input
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              className="search-field"
            />
            <button type="submit" className="search-button">
              <img src={IconLoupe} alt="" />
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="col-md-12">
        <Tabs
          defaultActiveKey="recents"
          id="uncontrolled-tab-example"
          className="mb-3 background-tabs"
        >
          <Tab eventKey="recents" title="Récents (7)">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <ul className="list-group">
                {tutorials &&
                  tutorials.map((tutorial, index) => (
                    <li
                      className={
                        "conseil-card" +
                        (index === currentIndex ? "active" : "")
                      }
                      onClick={() => setActiveTutorial(tutorial, index)}
                      key={index}
                    >
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        width="16"
                        height="16"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="bi bi-grip-vertical"
                        viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                      >
                        <path d="M7 2a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm3 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zM7 5a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm3 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zM7 8a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm3 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm-3 3a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm3 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm-3 3a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm3 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z" />
                      </svg>
                      <p>{tutorial.isPack ? "test" : "{tutorial.message}"}</p>
                      <div className="conseil-card-title">
                        Titre : {tutorial.title} - {tutorial.isPack ? "Pack oui" : "Pack non"}
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  ))}
              </ul>

              <button
                className="m-3 btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
                onClick={removeAllTutorials}
              >
                Modifier (Soon)
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-12">
              {currentTutorial ? (
                <div>
                  <h4>Conseil</h4>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <strong>Titre:</strong>
                    </label>{" "}
                    {currentTutorial.title}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <strong>Message:</strong>
                    </label>{" "}
                      //HERE I NEED DISPLAY message or messages
                    {currentTutorial.messages.map((number) => number + 1)}
                  </div>
                  <div></div>

                  <Link
                    to={"/tutorials/" + currentTutorial.id}
                    className="badge badge-warning"
                  >
                    Edit
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <br />
                  <p>Veuillez cliquer sur un conseil...</p>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey="favourite" title="Mes conseils favoris (3)">
            test2
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey="searched" title="« Rhinite allergique » (17)" disabled>
            test3
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TutorialsList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if image is pack and then render messages by going through the messages array and only showing message object message property.

This is pseudocode that you should follow in implementation

```
// assuming we have image object accessible as `image`
if (image.isPack) {
  return image.messages.map(msg => (
    <div key={msg.id}>
      {msg.message}
    </div>
  ))
}

return (
  <div>
    {image.message}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks you, but my displaying is in my render
Look this : https://codepen.io/ilaan16/pen/eYRKgOm

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code, so it stays here for a reference.

Comment: I'd probably do something like `[].concat(currentTutorial.message || currentTutorial.messages.map(msg => msg.message)).map(msg => <div key={msg.id}>{msg}</div>)`

Comment: The reason for the first bit is because I like the idea of shaping things into a familiar type before rendering, so I'd probably do that before returning the JSX, but equally you could do:

```
currentTutorial.message || currentTutorial.messages.map((number) => number + 1)
```
```

Comment: @Jamie Dixon you advise me to create a component that will return me what i need to display?